# My asterisk box program isn't working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

so I am supposed to be making a program that creates a box out of asteriks and so far it doesn't display correctly, sometimes the columns are too small, sometimes too big, but never where they need to be. can someone please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox {

    public static void drawBar(int length){
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

    }
    public static void drawHeight(int height, int length){
        int h = 0;
        while (h++ < length - 2){
            System.out.print("*");
            int h1 = 0;
            while (h1++ < length - 2){
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println(" *");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the length of the Box: ");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the height!: ");
        int height = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        drawBar(length);
        drawHeight(height, length);
        drawBar(length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you don't have a `println` in `drawBar` to end the line
- you compare `h` to `length` rather than `height` in `drawHeight`

Just a style comment: it might be clearer if your method produces a string of a given length and then the print methods are all in one place:

```
private String repeat(char ch, int len) {
    char chars = new char[len];
    Arrays.fill(chars, ch);
    return new String(chars);
}

println(repeat('*', length));
for (int l = 0; l < length - 2; l++)
    println("*" + repeat(' ', length - 2) + "*");
println(repeat('*', length));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox {

    public static void drawBar(int length){
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    public static void drawHeight(int height, int length){
        int h = 0;
        while (h++ < length - 1){
            System.out.print("*");
            int h1 = 0;
            while (h1++ < length-1){
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println("*");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the length of the Box: ");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the height!: ");
        int height = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        drawBar(length);
        drawHeight(height, length);
        drawBar(length);
    }
}
```

This seems ok.. though